# Can't install Visual Studio project templates

Tags: visual-studio, f#, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to create an F# project in Visual Studio 2015 Community. However, before I can do that I have to install the F# tools. Unfortunately, every time I try to install them (or any other tools for that matter) I get this error

[image]

and have no idea why. Anybody know how to fix this?